# Simple matrix class - version 2

Tags: c++, performance, matrix

As suggested on my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27573/c-simple-matrix-class-improve-coding), I am posting my revised code for feedback.

One thing that caught my attention is that my program actually runs slower after adding the modifications.  It was previously running near 128 iterations per second on a single core machine and 382 in a 4-core machine.  It now runs at 125 in the single core and 360 in the 4-core machine. I am not sure the way I was managing memory in my first version is faster or if I implemented it wrong.

Grid3d.h:

```
#ifndef _GRID3D_
#define _GRID3D_

#include <iostream>

class Grid3d
{
private:
    size_t M, N, L;
    double* buffer;
    size_t compute_index(size_t, size_t, size_t) const;

public:
    //Constructores
    Grid3d(size_t,size_t,size_t);
    Grid3d();
    Grid3d(const Grid3d&);
    ~Grid3d();

    //Operadores
    double& operator()(size_t, size_t, size_t);
    double  operator()(size_t, size_t, size_t) const;
    Grid3d& operator=(Grid3d);

    //Acceso
    int get_L();
    int get_M();
    int get_N();
    double get(size_t,size_t,size_t) const;
    void reset();
};

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &,Grid3d);
#endif
```

Grid3d.cc:

```
#include "Grid3d.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructores 
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Constructor
Grid3d::Grid3d(size_t M, size_t N, size_t L)
      : M(M), N(N), L(L), buffer(new double[M * N * L])
{
    for (size_t l=0;l<M*N*L;l++){
        buffer[l] = NAN;
    }
}

//Constructor vacío
Grid3d::Grid3d()
    :M(0), N(0), L(0)
{
    buffer = NULL;
}


//Constructor copia
Grid3d::Grid3d(const Grid3d &other)
    :M(other.M), N(other.N), L(other.L)
{
    buffer = new double[M * N * L];
    for (size_t l=0;l<M*N*L;l++){
        buffer[l] = other.buffer[l];
    }
}

//Destructor
Grid3d::~Grid3d() { delete [] buffer; }

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operadores 
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//Access operator ():
double& Grid3d::operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k)
{
    assert(i >= 0 and i < M);
    assert(j >= 0 and j < N);
    assert(k >= 0 and k < L);
    return buffer[compute_index(i, j, k)];
}

//Access operator () const:
double Grid3d::operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const
{
    assert(i >= 0 and i < M);
    assert(j >= 0 and j < N);
    assert(k >= 0 and k < L);
    return buffer[compute_index(i, j, k)];
}

//Assignment operator
Grid3d& Grid3d::operator=(Grid3d other)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(M, other.M);
    swap(N, other.N);
    swap(L, other.L);
    swap(buffer, other.buffer);
    return *this;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Acceso 
//------------------------------------------------------------------
size_t Grid3d::compute_index(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const
{
    return k * (M * N) + i * N + j;
}

int Grid3d::get_L()
{
    return L;
}

int Grid3d::get_M()
{
    return M;
}

int Grid3d::get_N()
{
    return N;
}

double Grid3d::get(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const
{
    assert(i >= 0 and i < M);
    assert(j >= 0 and j < N);
    assert(k >= 0 and k < L);
    return buffer[compute_index(i, j, k)];
}

void Grid3d::reset()
{
    for (size_t l=0;l<M*N*L;l++){
        buffer[l] = NAN;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Others
//------------------------------------------------------------------

//cout
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os , Grid3d g)
{
    int M = g.get_M();
    int N = g.get_N();
    int L = g.get_L();

    for (int k=0;k<L;k++){
        cout << "k = " << k << endl;
        for (int i=0;i<M;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
                cout.width(10);
                os << setprecision(3) << g.get(i,j,k)<< " ";
            }
            os << endl;
        }   
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization on? This is probably important, as with optimization off, compute_index will not be inlined (for example).

Comment: As another note, using NANs may slow down your code considerably. Floating point operations with NaNs are slower than those without.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since it's been covered in detail on your previous post, but I'd like to again strongly urge you to use a single dimensional vector. With optimizations, it will be as fast as a raw array. It will provide much cleaner and smaller code at literally 0 cost. I consider a bare array the wrong choice here unless performance actually does be one a concern and a bare array is faster (and it wouldn't be).

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use English in your comments as well. Not only is it good practice, but it also helps in case you ever need to, say, post your code to an English-language online Q&A or code review site.

Comment: @ruds I am compiling using gcc 4.7 with -O2.
I initialize the grid points as NAN, then i change each point to its propper value(which is generally not 0). That way, if I forget to define the value of a grid point I notice imediatley, so i am not doing float operation with nans.

Comment: Please show us the test harness you're using -- it's hard to evaluate what's slower if we don't know what's actually running.

Answer (score 7):

I will expand on this when I have more time, but a few things jumped out:

---

`get_M`/`get_L`/`get_N` should return a `std::size_t`, not an `int`.

---

`get_M`/`get_L`/`get_N` should be const.

---

It might make sense in your field of study, but to me, NAN is weird for the initial value. I would expect the initial values to be either undefined or 0. Whatever works best for you though. Initializing to NAN would, after all, provide a few convenient properties.

---

All of the `size_t` in the header should be [`std::size_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237370/does-stdsize-t-make-sense-in-c).

---

Rather than duplicate the exact same code, the constructor should use `reset`.

---

Be careful with `using namespace std;`, even in implementation files. If you want to read way more than you ever wanted to on it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The "tl;dr" of it is that a potentially application breaking bug might happen years down the road do to a change a dozen files away, but that can all be avoided with 5 extra characters (`std::`).

---

When outputting potentially huge chunks of data, try not to flush until you either need to or the end (in single threaded applications, that's almost always going to be the end).

In particular, std::endl is *not* equivalent to `"\n"`. `std::cout << "\n";` pushes a new line into `std::cout`s buffer. `std::cout << std::endl;` pushes a newline into `std::cout`'s buffer and then flushes the buffer. This means that your `operator<<` isn't really using buffered IO since it flushes after every output.

Simple fix: use "\n" and then just do `std::flush(std::cout);` (or `std::cout << std::flush`) at the end.

---

`cout.width(10);` in your `operator<<` should be `os.width(10)`.

Comment: +1; instead of creating a separate answer, I'll just add a comment: in addition, I'd also replace all uses of `int` with `std::size_t` in `operator <<` (which should also preferably take `Grid3d` by const-ref, 4 x 64-bit + alignment may be a bit too much for pass-by-value). Also, regardless of whether the OP adopts `std::vector`, I'd probably also use `std::copy` in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the performance degradation is caused because in your previous version, `operator<<` took a `Grid3d&`, and in this version it takes a `Grid3d`. Your `operator<<` signature should be

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Grid3d&);
```

As another code improvement, you should change your copy constructor:

```
Grid3d::Grid3d(const Grid3d &other)
  : L(other.L), M(other.M), N(other.N)
{
    buffer = new double[L * M * N];
    std::memcpy(buffer, other.buffer, M * N * L * sizeof(double));
}
```

`memcpy` may give you better performance than the `for` loop you wrote.

Comment: A small note, but the order of `delete` and `new` in your copy constructor should be the other way around. This ensures strong exception safety in the case that `new` throws.

Comment: Well, it can't be quite in the opposite order, but I'll edit the code to take your comment into account.

Comment: Will M, N and L of the object be left containing the wrong values if `new` throws?

Comment: Err... on further thought, this is a constructor, so if `new` throws, the object get cleaned up and no longer exists, so the state of L, M and N is irrelevant. Sorry to confuse :-(

Comment: **BANG** you are dead the shuttle just blew up. You are deleting an initialized member `Buffer`. It is not leaked . This is a **CONSTRUCTOR** so it has not previously been initialized.

Comment: prefer `std::copy()` worst case it has the same performance as `std::memcpy`. Best case there is some cool optimization in the standard that makes it faster (unlikely but you never know).

Comment: @Loki Astari, yes actually that line was generating a "core" so i commented it.

Comment: @ruds I is not likely that the performance degradation is caused by that. I used that function for testing purposes only. The only functions that are used intensively are "operator()" and "get()", mostly "operator()".

Comment: @LokiAstari ugh, oops. I had assignment operator in my head. I should get more sleep before answering these...

Comment: @ruds: No problem. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 3):

So you do not have to handle NULL created a zero sized array here (and use the initializer list):

```
//Constructor vacío
Grid3d::Grid3d()
    :M(0), N(0), L(0)
{
    buffer = NULL;
}

// Prefer
Grid3d::Grid3d()
    :M(0), N(0), L(0), buffer(new double[N*M*L])
{}
```

By creating the array like this, the rest of you code does not need to have a special case for NULL buffer. The code just looks the same.

Now that looks very similar to your other constructor.
You could potentially just combine the two.

Prefer to use the initializer liest (even in the copy constructor)

```
Grid3d::Grid3d(const Grid3d &other)
    :M(other.M), N(other.N), L(other.L)
    ,buffer(new double[M * N * L])
{
    for (size_t l=0;l<M*N*L;l++){
        buffer[l] = other.buffer[l];
    }
}
```

For the const version of your access operator. Just make it call the non const version. (We know that neither version actually mutate the object so there is no harm in casting away constness). The const version returns a value so it is not exposing any data for modification:

```
double Grid3d::operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const
{
    return const_cast<Grid3d>(*this)(i,j,k);
}
```

All the following should be const:

```
int Grid3d::get_L()
int Grid3d::get_M()
int Grid3d::get_N()
```

Pass by const reference when you can to prevent an expensive copy.

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os , Grid3d const& g)
                                               //      ^^^^^^
```

Prefer not to use `\n` instead of `std::endl`. It has no major benefits and can slow code down dramatically. If you want to guarantee a flush print the whole structure first then use `std::endl` instad of the last '\n'.